# How to implement a two-finger double-click in Android?

Tags: android, multi-touch, gesture, double-click

I know how to detect a double-click and a two-finger touch event, but how can I combine these to react so somebody needs to double click with two fingers?

By default, Android has the long press to act as a second form of clicking, but I'm specifically looking for a two-finger double-click.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I wanted a simple and reusable interface that listens for two finger double taps and behaves like GestureDetector.  So that you could use it like this (all cut & paste runnable code):

```
public class Example extends Activity {
    SimpleTwoFingerDoubleTapDetector multiTouchListener = new SimpleTwoFingerDoubleTapDetector() {
        @Override
        public void onTwoFingerDoubleTap() {
            // Do what you want here, I used a Toast for demonstration
            Toast.makeText(Example.this, "Two Finger Double Tap", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    // Override onCreate() and anything else you want

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if(multiTouchListener.onTouchEvent(event))
            return true;
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

I created SimpleTwoFingerDoubleTapDetector. (It's a long name, but it is descriptive. You can rename it as anything you want.) Save this new file inside your project or as a library:

```
public abstract class SimpleTwoFingerDoubleTapDetector {
    private static final int TIMEOUT = ViewConfiguration.getDoubleTapTimeout() + 100;
    private long mFirstDownTime = 0;
    private boolean mSeparateTouches = false;
    private byte mTwoFingerTapCount = 0;

    private void reset(long time) {
        mFirstDownTime = time;
        mSeparateTouches = false;
        mTwoFingerTapCount = 0;
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getActionMasked()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if(mFirstDownTime == 0 || event.getEventTime() - mFirstDownTime > TIMEOUT) 
                reset(event.getDownTime());
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            if(event.getPointerCount() == 2)  
                mTwoFingerTapCount++;
            else 
                mFirstDownTime = 0;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if(!mSeparateTouches)
                mSeparateTouches = true;
            else if(mTwoFingerTapCount == 2 && event.getEventTime() - mFirstDownTime < TIMEOUT) {
                onTwoFingerDoubleTap();
                mFirstDownTime = 0;
                return true;
            }
        }               

        return false;
    }

    public abstract void onTwoFingerDoubleTap();
}
```

First, a few notes about Android (one-touch) **GestureDetector**:

- Android's `onDoubleTap()` event uses a standard timeout value from ViewConfiguration. I refer to the same time.
- They measure the elapsed time from the first tap's finger-down event to the second tap's finger-down event, and then broadcast `onDoubleTap()` and `onDoubleTapEvent()`.

  - `onDoubleTap()` is fired only when the second tap's finger-down event occurs.
  - `onDoubleTapEvent()` is fired for every action by the second tap: down, move, and up.

A few notes on **SimpleTwoFingerDoubleTapDetector**:

- My timeout is measured from the first finger-down event to the last finger-*up* event to prevent false double-tap notifications. I added a little extra time to the default ViewConfiguration double tap timeout to account for this.
- Android's GestureDetector measures slop (how far apart the two taps are). I didn't see the need for this here, nor did I check the distance between the two fingers on each tap.
- I only broadcast one event `onTwoFingerDoubleTap()`.

---

**Final note:**
You can *easily* change this to behave like an OnTouchListener:

1. Change SimpleTwoFingerDoubleTapDetector's definition:

   ```
   public abstract class SimpleTwoFingerDoubleTapListener implements OnTouchListener {
   ```
2. Add a new class variable:

   ```
   private View mFirstView;
   ```
3. Change the `ACTION_DOWN` case:

   ```
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
       if(mFirstDownTime == -1 || mFirstView != v || hasTimedOut(event.getEventTime())) {
           mFirstView = v;
           reset(event.getDownTime());
       }
       break;
   ```
4. Pass `mFirstView` inside the `ACTION_UP` case:

   ```
   onTwoFingerDoubleTap(mFirstView);
   ```
5. Last, change the `onTwoFingerDoubleTap()` method to reflect which View was tapped:

   ```
   public abstract void onTwoFingerDoubleTap(View v);
   ```

Comment: This answer is awesome!

Comment: I've tried this code (thanks!) and it didn't work - I was only getting ACTION_DOWN events. I believe the onTouchEvent() function must return True (for ACTION_DOWN) or otherwise ACTION_UP wont be received afterwards. Refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16495363/1277048

Comment: Thanks, even though it didn't work. It is helping me get to the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a double-click listener I created to detect a two-finger double click.

Variables used:

```
private GestureDetector gesture;
private View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;
boolean click1 = false;
boolean click2 = false;
long first = 0;
long second = 0;
```

In the activity's `onCreate()` to register the touch events:

```
gesture = new GestureDetector(getApplicationContext(), new SimpleOnGestureListener(){
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
    }
});
gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gesture.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
};
```

Outside of `onCreate()` inside the activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {   
    try {
        int action = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
        //capture the event when the user lifts their fingers, not on the down press
        //to make sure they're not long pressing
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
            //timer to get difference between clicks
            Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

            //detect number of fingers, change to 1 for a single-finger double-click, 3 for a triple-finger double-click, etc.
            if (event.getPointerCount() == 2) {
                if (!click1) {
                    //if this is the first click, then there hasn't been a second
                    //click yet, also record the time
                    click1 = true;
                    click2 = false;
                    first = now.getTimeInMillis(); 
                } else if (click1) {
                    //if this is the second click, record its time 
                    click2 = true;
                    second = now.getTimeInMillis();

                    //if the difference between the 2 clicks is less than 500 ms (1/2 second)
                    //Math.abs() is used because you need to be able to detect any sequence of clicks, rather than just in pairs of two
                    //(e.g. click1 could be registered as a second click if the difference between click1 and click2 > 500 but
                    //click2 and the next click1 is < 500)
                    if (Math.abs(second-first) < 500) {

                        //do something!!!!!!

                    } else if (Math.abs(second-first) >= 500) {
                        //reset to handle more clicks
                        click1 = false;
                        click2 = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e){

    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `if (click1 && click2 && Math.abs(second-first) < 500) {...}` is overkill. You cannot get to this particular part of the code unless `click1 && click2` is already true. To get here, you have to pass through this: `if (click1) { click2 = true; ... }`. The same effect can be achieved with `if (Math.abs(second-first) < 500) { //do something!!!!!! } else {click1 = false; click2 = false;}`

Comment: @Nezam I haven't used this code in years now, but I'm not sure why that'd be - it worked just fine in our app