# Why does an onTouchListener not report MotionEvent.ACTION_UP until an onClickListener is specified?

Tags: android

I have discovered some weird functionality when using android...

If I specify a ConstraintLayout's onTouchListener like so:

```java
ConstraintLayout clSend = fragment.findViewById(R.id.alert_message_send_layout);
clSend.setOnTouchListener((view, event) -> {
    Log.d("onTouch event: %d", event);
            
    return view.onTouchEvent(event);
});
```

Then I press the layout, I get the result:

```
onTouch event: 0 // MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
```

Which is expected, however when holding on the press and releasing after a short period (2-3 seconds), onTouch() is only called for the ACTION_DOWN event. I would expect there to be a MotionEvent.ACTION_UP event but no...

But it gets weirder...
If I repeat the above but add an on**Click**Listener like so:

```java
ConstraintLayout clSend = fragment.findViewById(R.id.alert_message_send_layout);
clSend.setOnClickListener(v -> {});
clSend.setOnTouchListener((view, event) -> {
    Log.d("onTouch event: %d", event);
            
    return view.onTouchEvent(event);
});
```

Then I get both an ACTION_DOWN event, and an ACTION_UP event.

***Does anyone have an explanation for this?***

I've checked the Documentation:
[View.OnTouchListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) and
[MotionEvent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent)

I've checked the [android issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:190923%2B)

I've checked here on StackOverflow.com but nothing explains it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"One final search to make sure I'm not being lazy..."

@Danpe answers it [perfectly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16495363/6558559):

> `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` Won't get called until the `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` occurred, a logical explanation for this is that it's impossible for an `ACTION_UP` to occur if an `ACTION_DOWN` never occurred before it.

So all that has to be done is:

```java
...
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    ...
    if (event == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        return true;
    }
    ...
}
```