# Android calendar view double click not support

Tags: android, double-click, calendarview

I want to ask if there is any support or a way to simulate the double click event to a calendar view like the 'touch' or 'hover' event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look into this answer where the user takes the double touch event and uses it as a [doubleclick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12556832/346309) or you can use the double tap in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16232779/346309).  Either way the design is up to you.