# Android multi finger gesture

Tags: android, gesture

I am working on multi finger gestures, I tried using Google gesture builder but it will not support for multi finger gestures, How to recognize two finger V shape gesture in android.?

Comment: try writing a custom gesture listener as show in this question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10682019/android-two-finger-rotation) also refer [link](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/multi.html) to work with multitouch

Comment: you can use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414680/how-to-implement-a-two-finger-double-click-in-android)

Comment: @yassine : Which one..?

Comment: @Vishwanath : Sam's answer, he explain how it's work

Comment: @yassine__ Can you give me Sam's answer link

Comment: @Vishwanath : http://stackoverflow.com/a/12556832/2424805

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure you can use a [`ScaleGestureDetector`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ScaleGestureDetector.html) for this.

After all a "V" from the top is just a pinch with some translation on the Y axis.

So I think you can analyse the focus point and scale factor to determine a "V" has taken place.

Here is a working example. In the end I didn't need to look at the scale. There are a couple of sensitivity values you can adjust such as the range of acceptable angles and the ratio of Y to X movement.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static class VListener extends
            ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        private float initialFocusX;
        private float initialFocusY;

        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            Log.d(TAG, String.format("%.2f,%.2f s:%.2f", detector.getFocusX(),
                    detector.getFocusY(), detector.getScaleFactor()));
            initialFocusX = detector.getFocusX();
            initialFocusY = detector.getFocusY();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            float deltaX = detector.getFocusX() - initialFocusX;
            float deltaY = detector.getFocusY() - initialFocusY;

            if (deltaY == 0) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Not a V, no Y movement");
                onNonV();
                return;
            }

            float yMovementRatio = Math.abs(deltaY / deltaX);
            if (yMovementRatio < 4) {
                Log.d(TAG,
                        String.format(
                                "Not a V, the ratio of Y movement to X was not high enough: %.2f",
                                yMovementRatio));
                onNonV();
                return;
            }

            float angle = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX));
            if (angle > 80 && angle < 100) {
                Log.d(TAG, "V!");
                onV();
                return;
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG,
                        String.format(
                                "Not a V, the angle shows the V was drawn in the wrong direction: %.2f",
                                angle));
                onNonV();
            }
        }

        protected void onV() {
        }

        protected void onNonV() {
        }
    }

    protected static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleGestureDetector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vTextIndicator);

        mScaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(this, new VListener() {
            @Override
            protected void onV() {
                t.setText("V!");
            }

            @Override
            protected void onNonV() {
                t.setText("Non V");
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        boolean retVal = mScaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return retVal || super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

}
```

`activity_main.xml` Layout is just:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/vTextIndicator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample app - [InteractiveChart.zip](http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/InteractiveChart.zip)

This links might help - [Draggin & Scaling](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scale.html) and [Handling Multi-Touch Gestures](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/multi.html)